# Launcher 3 and it Purpose

Tags: launcher

What does a launcher3 do?  and why would you want to  Launch another one on your phone?

and what does it mean that on Google when it states that you have used launcher 3?

Answer (score 0):

Launcher3 is a home screen app that allows you to launch apps. You always use it. You may want to use another launcher if you hate the default layout of your home screen